# How to jump to the next/prev section in vim-latex?

Tags: vim-latex

Could not quickly find the answer in google.

Comment: Really?  First hit: https://www.google.de/search?q=jump+to+section+vim-latex

Comment: @HenriMenke Well, that is not a part of vim-latex. I'm asking about functionality (that I expect to be) built into vim-latex suite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move between section boundaries with `[[`, `[]`, `][`, and `]]`

This comes from README in the main [vimtex Github repository](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex).

Comment: How about subsections?